# Java program using arrays that outputs numbers of girls in different categories

Tags: java

So I am doing a code for girl scout cookies. My array length is how many girl scouts there are and they each have a certain number of cookies. The program gets those two variables from the user and then at the end it shows with four different criteria how many girls sold how many cookies. My question is if there is another for loop I can use at the end where I assign girls into different categories. So what else can I do instead of for(int x : cookiesSold)?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class girlScoutCookies {

    public static  void main(String[] args) {

        int cookies1 = 0;
        int cookies2 = 0;
        int cookies3 = 0;
        int cookies4 = 0;
        int numOfGirls = 0;

        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many girls are in the girl scouts?");

        numOfGirls = n.nextInt();

        if(numOfGirls <= 0){
            System.out.println("There should be at least one girl selling cookies");
        }else{
            numOfGirls = numOfGirls;
        }

        int[] cookiesSold = new int[numOfGirls];

        for(int i = 0; i<numOfGirls;i++){
            System.out.println("What is the number of cookies the girl has sold");
            cookiesSold[i] = n.nextInt();
        }

        for(int x : cookiesSold){ 
            System.out.println("This is x: " +x);

            if(x >= 0 && x <= 10 ){
                 cookies1++;
            }else if(x >= 11 && x<=20 ){
                cookies2++;
            }else if(x >= 21 && x<=30 ){
                cookies3++;
            }else if(x >= 31 ){
                cookies4++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The number of girls that sold the following cookies are:\n 0 to 10 cookies:\t " + cookies1 + "\n 11 to 20 cookies:\t " + cookies2 + "\n 21 to 30 cookies:\t " + cookies3 + "\n 31 or more cookies: \t " +cookies4);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "assign girls into different categories"?  You don't have any girls, only integers.

Comment: So, first, "numOfGirls = numOfGirls" is a pointless line of code. Second, what you're asking isn't clear, I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: For the last part i was wondering of another way to write for(int x:cookiesSold). But i got it now it should have been: for(int i = 0; i<numOfGirls;i++){ 
   if(cookiesSold[i] >= 0 && cookiesSold[i]  <= 10 ){
    cookies1++;
   }else if(cookiesSold[i]  >= 11 && cookiesSold[i] <=20 ){
    cookies2++;
   }else if(cookiesSold[i]  >= 21 && cookiesSold[i] <=30 ){
    cookies3++;
   }else if(cookiesSold[i]  >= 31 ){
    cookies4++;
   }

  }

Comment: What you really want to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 4 variables, use an array:

```
// Remove these:
int cookies1 = 0;
int cookies2 = 0;
int cookies3 = 0;
int cookies4 = 0;
// Replace with this:
int[] cookies = new int[4];
```

Next, use integer arithmetic to find the index from the `cookiesSold` value. Note that you must cap the index at 3:

```
// Remove all this:
if(x >= 0 && x <= 10 ){
    cookies1++;
}else if(x >= 11 && x<=20 ){
    cookies2++;
}else if(x >= 21 && x<=30 ){
    cookies3++;
}else if(x >= 31 ){
    cookies4++;
}
// Replace with just this line:
cookies[Math.min(x / 10, 3)]++;
```

For a more robust solution, use the length of the array, so to increase the number of slots, just change the size of the array:

```
cookies[Math.min(x / 10, cookies.length - 1)]++;
```